# How to implement stripe subscription with three months initial upfront payment

Tags: python, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm building a checkout page where a user subscribes to a $10 /month product. However, when the user signs up, they are required to pay for the first three months upfront (that's $30). If they wish to auto renew their subscription thereafter, we'll fallback to them paying $10 each month.

The frontend is a Single Page React app while the backend is built with python (flask). I'm collecting their payment details on the frontend using the `CardElement`. Next I create their payment method and send the details to the backend as follows

```js
const stripe = useStripe();
const elements = useElements();
...
const { paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
     element: elements.getElement("card")!,
})

// this is a post request to the backend
const subscriptionRes = await ApiRequestAction.subscribeAccount({
      paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id,
      ...
});
```

On the backend, I start by creating the customer with the payment details as follows

```py
...
request_data = request.get_json();
payment_method_id = request_data["paymentMethodId"]  # The payment method id sent from the frontend
...
stripe_customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email=...,
            name=...,
            payment_method=payment_method_id,
            invoice_settings={"default_payment_method": payment_method_id}
        )
```

This is where my nightmare begins. My first approach to solving the problem is to create a `Subscription Schedule` with two phases. The first phase has an `iteration` of **3** and the second phase has an `iteration` of **1** as follows

```py
...
subscription_sch = stripe.SubscriptionSchedule.create(
            customer=stripe_customer.id,
            start_date='now',
            end_behavior='release',
            phases=[
                {
                    'items': [{'price': stripe_price_id, 'quantity': 3}],
                    'iterations': 3,
                },
                {
                    'items': [{'price': stripe_price_id, 'quantity': 1}],
                    'iterations': 1,
                },
            ],
        )
```

But with this approach,

- I'm not sure how to finalize the payment on the frontend. If I were to create a more traditional `Subscription` instance, I'll retrieve the `latest_invoice` and send the `PaymentIntent` secret of that invoice to the frontend for the payment to be completed. [However, from what I read](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#invoice-lifecycle), the user will only be charged one hour after the first invoice is generated which is not ideal for my use-case.
- I'm also not sure how to complete the payment on the frontend

The second approach was to create a one time $30 invoice pay-off for those first three months and then create a `Subscription` for them thereafter but I'm not sure how to go about that.

I'd love to know your thoughts on how you implemented something similar, or how you think this should be properly implemented. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirements from your case that:

1. Create subscription with 3 months payment ($10 * 3 = $30) in the first invoice (first billing cycle) and free for next two billing cycles
2. Collect payment immediately without one-hour draft waiting period
3. Start charging from fourth cycle with $10

This is possible with following steps:

1. Create a subscription schedule to collect 3 months of payment in the phase[0] and no payment collection in the next two billing cycles by using trial in phase[1]. After the subscription schedule is released, the customer will be charged with $10 monthly from fourth month onwards. Below code expand `subscription` object to get the `latest_invoice` of the subscription.

```
options = {
  customer: panels[1].id,
  start_date: 'now',
  end_behavior: 'release',
  phases: [
    {
      items: [
        {
          price: 'price_123',
          quantity: 3
        }
      ],
      iterations: 1
    }, {
      items: [
        {
          price: 'price_123',
          quantity: 1
        }
      ],
      iterations: 2,
      trial: true,
    }
  ],
  expand: ['subscription']
}
const subscriptionSchedule = await stripe.subscriptions.create(options);
```

2. Finalise the invoice from Step 1 immediately without waiting for one-hour draft

```
const invoice = await stripe.invoices.finalizeInvoice(
  subscriptionSchedule.subscription.latest_invoice,
  {
    expand: ['payment_intent'],
  }
);
```

3. Confirm the payment intent from Step 2 only when the payment intent status is in `requires_confirmation`

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
  invoice.payment_intent,
);
```

Since your code has already set `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` on the customer, the invoice will use the default payment method for invoice payment of the subscription.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. 
After a lot of playing around, I ended up doing almost the same thing in your answer except that instead of making the 2nd and 3rd phase a trial period, I'm setting the quantity to 0 so that the invoice price will be $0 for those two months. Do you think I'm on track by doing it this way?

Comment: Yes, setting the quantity of phase[1] to 0 should work as well. You probably will need additional phase that phase[2] is set to quantity 1, so that the subscription will start charging $10 from fourth month onwards.